# picture display with if statements

Tags: php

i have a database that stores all my inventory items in # slots. values of items range from 1-50. each value represents a picture stored on the server. here is the code i wrote which will display x picture depending on the value listed in the database. although this code works i am wondering if someone can give me a better way to write this code because as is if i have 50 items i will have over 6000 lines of code based on how many inventory slots are available.

```
require_once 'includes/database.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE username '".$_SESSION['username']."'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
$inv1 = $row["inv1"];

if($inv1 == 1) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/1.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 2) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/2.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 3) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/3.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 4) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/4.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 5) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/5.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 6) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/6.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 7) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/7.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 8) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/8.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 9) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/9.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
if($inv1 == 10) {
$inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/10.png">';
$smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write like this:

```
require_once 'includes/database.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE username '".$_SESSION['username']."'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $inv1 = $row["inv1"];
    $inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/'. intval($inv1). '.png">';
    $smarty->assign('inv1a', $inv1a);
}
```

I'm using intval around $inv1 because I assumed that you were fetching only integers from the database.

If this is not the case, remove change `intval($inv1)` to `$inv1`

The function `intval` casts the input to integer, that will prevent possible XSS attacks like a file intentionally named "index.php.png"

Sanitize the output everytime you plan to use it in your webpage, and make sure that you're loading the content that you're expecting to load.

Comment: thanks for the help this worked perfect and saved me allot of time, and yes all integers.

Comment: good to know, if you're using just integers, then use intval. that way you can be sure that you're only mutating the string with integers.

Comment: can u explain to me what you mean by sanitizing my output?

Comment: By "sanitizing your output" I meant that you have to make sure that whatever dynamic variable you're using to write either to an HTML page, or to use in any part of your code, you have to make sure that it is what you're expecting it to be. In your case, $inv1 can only be integers, so by using `intval` around that variable name, you're making sure that `$inv1` will only be a number. That's just one way to sanitize input/output. If you fail to sanitize dynamic data (especially user provided data), it can lead to disastrous events like SQL injection, XSS or in the best case scenario plain errors

Comment: If you're not too familiar with input/output sanitization, I strongly recommend you start here: http://php.net/filter_var `filter_var` is a PHP instruction that allows you to sanitize email address, URLs, numbers, floats, ip addresses, etc right off the bat.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe (actually I don't know what your code is even supposed to do, this may not work at all) :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $inv1 = $row["inv1"];
    $inv1a = '<img src="images/armor/'.$inv1.'.png">';
    $smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
    $inv1 = $row["inv1"];
    $inv1a = "<img src='images/armor/" . $inv1 . ".png'>";
    $smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
```

This code is assuming that the image will only ever be found in the *armor* directory. However you can set that as a variable if you need to switch between image types, like so:

```
$itemType = "armor";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
    $inv1 = $row["inv1"];
    $inv1a = "<img src='images/" . $itemType . "/" . $inv1 . ".png'>";
    $smarty->assign('inv1a',$inv1a);
}
```